# collection of system properties using web browser

Tags: java, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajax.net

Hi I am doing distributed computing environment. For the applications need to get distributed to different clients connected to the server in the network, I preferred to collect the client's system properties like free memory available in the client's system, so that I could distribute the application according to that efficiently. Please give me some good idea. Thanks in advance

Comment: what OS ar the clients running?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged this with Java, I am assuming you are using a Java based client server model. What is the communication model between the client and the server here? RMI? Some proprietary protocol? Or is it a Java applet based app running in the browser?

Update based on clarification : In that case you can you can always collect the system properties inside the applet code and send them back to the server (maybe by using a servlet?)

Comment: actually communication established through web browser interface...it is a Java applet based app running in the browser